# Pretty way to define class functions that all call same function with different parameters

Tags: python

I'm writing a class that has a bunch of member functions that all call the same function with different parameters. The way I have it written right now is like:

```
class ExampleClass:
    def a_function(self,args):
        do_something

    def func1(self):
        return self.a_function(arg1)

    def func2(self):
        return self.a_function(arg2)
        .
        .
        .
```

This seems incredibly redundant and is a pain to deal with since it takes up so much space. Is this the best way to deal with class functions that all have the same structure or is there a better way to deal with this?

Comment: Why don't you pass the parameter as an argument to the method? `def func1(self, some_arg): return self.a_function(some_arg)`

Comment: Or just even make `a_function` directly accessible. What's the purpose of the multiple methods?

Comment: I dont want whoever is using this class to have to know what arguments they need to pass in to call 'a_function'

Comment: I don't understand your use case.  Why do you have this extra layer in your design?  It appears that any call to `obj.func1` should be replaced by the `a_function` equivalent.

Comment: That doesn't make sense to me. Why not? This is almost certainly an XY problem with an outcome that won't satisfy what you're hoping to achieve. All your code is either directly accessible by the user or it's a remote API and none of it is.

Comment: i see what the OP means "I dont want whoever is using this class to have to know...". It does make sense. But in that case, your goal is to provide separate func1, func2, etc. to the users, probably with very intuitive function names. So i don't see there is anyway you can avoid individually defining them

Comment: @roganjosh Its an api.  In my example, func1...funcn are the functions that will be called by anyone using the api. a_function isn't supposed to be called outside of member functions

Comment: @Chris how does it make sense? You can't have anything hidden or inaccessible locally. You can _imply_ "don't play with this directly" but nothing is private. That's just Python.

Comment: @roganjosh i think of it not as a matter of technicality issue. it's just a matter of courtesy. Even if the whole class is accessible to the user, if they just need to use it, it's easier to not having to read instructions on what parameters to use for `a_function()`

Comment: @Chris so start the method name with an underscore, as is the convention. Anyone serious in Python will know exactly what it implies and it's just up to them whether they choose to ignore the implication. "We're all adults here"

Comment: @roganjosh I already have the function started with an underscore. Thats not my question. I want to know if there is a better, more pythonic way of defining all those accessible class functions.

Comment: @roganjosh I'm not arguing against that. just saying I see OP's point here

Comment: And I gave you one; pass the parameter as an argument to your proxy method. That's all you're doing currently anyway, in a load of unnecessary different methods. How do you hope to document all these different methods in a sensible way when they all call the same underlying method? It doesn't do anything but make your API _more_ confusing.

Answer (score 2):

Since functions are first class objects in Python you can create and return one inside of another. This means you could do define a helper function and use it inside the class to get rid of some of the boilerplate code:

```
class ExampleClass:
    def a_function(self, *args):
        print('do_something to {}'.format(args[0]))

    def _call_a_function(arg):
        def func(self):
            return self.a_function(arg)
        return func

    func1 = _call_a_function(1)
    func2 = _call_a_function(2)
    func3 = _call_a_function(3)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    example = ExampleClass()
    example.func1() # -> do_something to 1
    example.func2() # -> do_something to 2
    example.func3() # -> do_something to 3
```

If you're using a fairly recent version of Python, you don't even have to write the helper function because there's a built-in one named [`partialmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partialmethod):

```
from functools import partialmethod  # Requires Python 3.4+

class ExampleClass2:
    def a_function(self, *args):
        print('do_something to {}'.format(args[0]))

    func1 = partialmethod(a_function, 1)
    func2 = partialmethod(a_function, 2)
    func3 = partialmethod(a_function, 3)
```

Comment: i was just about to suggest this idea. nice example code

Comment: Is this a way of dealing with a standard design pattern? It seems to me that `a_function` does too much.

Comment: @roganjosh: Not sure what you mean by "standard design pattern" nor about `a_function` doing too much. Creating a function that encapsulates a repeated sequence of processing is a "design patthern" that's as old as the hills. There are also other ways of implementing it in Python, I simply picked what I felt was the most obvious one.

Comment: A function should do one thing. The fact that all of these helper methods end up calling the same method but with different arguments suggests to me that `a_function` does an awful lot of different things. If it didn't, you'd surely expose it directly and explain how it handles different inputs. Then `a_function` should call different functions based on its input. All I'm envisioning is that `a_function` has some mega body that handles all different functionality within itself.

Comment: @roganjosh: Well, the `_call_a_function()` function only has one purpose. It's hard to say much about `a_function()` itself other than it apparently accepts an argument which can have different values, something which is very, very common and doesn't, in general, indicate how much or what kind of processing is going to occur within the function accepting it.