# Is it possible to autogenerate functions with arguments?

Tags: python, functools

I have a method that draws a line or a patch of any shape I need given the name of the shape and some arguments, it works fine:

```
def draw_a_shape(ax, is_patch_not_line, shapename, **kwargs):
  ...
```

Now I need to have 30+ functions like `draw_a_square_patch`, `draw_an_ellipse_outline` etc. I can implement them in a trivial way, as below, but it's a bit painful:

```
def draw_a_square_patch(ax, **kwargs):
  draw_a_shape(ax=ax, is_patch_not_line=True, shapename='a_square', **kwargs)
def draw_a_square_outline(ax, **kwargs):
  draw_a_shape(ax=ax, is_patch_not_line=False, shapename='a_square', **kwargs)
def draw_an_ellipse_patch(ax, **kwargs):
  draw_a_shape(ax=ax, is_patch_not_line=True, shapename='an_ellipse', **kwargs)
def draw_an_ellipse_outline(ax, **kwargs):
  draw_a_shape(ax=ax, is_patch_not_line=False, shapename='an_ellipse', **kwargs)
.........
```

I wonder if there is a way to do it using a **loop**, and maybe something like `setattr`? I am adding an invalid code below, just to explain what I mean:

```
for shapename in ['a_circle', 'a_square', ...]:
  for is_patch_not_line in [False, True]:
    new_func_name = "draw_" + shapename + "_"
    if is_patch_not_line:
      new_func_name += "patch"
    else:
      new_func_name += "outline"
    global.setattr(new_func_name, "ax, **kwargs", ...)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pretty way to define class functions that all call same function with different parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52994679/pretty-way-to-define-class-functions-that-all-call-same-function-with-different)

Comment: why do you need to have 30+ functions? you could just call `draw_a_shape` directly while varying the `shapename` argument and that seems perfectly readable to me

Comment: @manveti - thanks but it does not, I think I have got to the level of that question more or less, but I wanted something like a loop

Comment: @JoshKatofsky - I am doing it for kids, I think it will be much easier for them. I can - and probably will - do a straightforward implementation, but a loop would be nicer.

Comment: Could you edit the question to clarify where your confusion is? If you understand `setattr` and `functools.partialmethod` it's hard to guess what more is left.

Comment: ah - yes that makes sense! this may be able to help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14078558/6867216

Comment: @JoshKatofsky I have seen it, but it seems to give no control over arguments

Comment: @manveti edited.

Comment: Ah, I misread and thought these were class methods. Josh's dupe target about `globals()[func_name]` is probably better than mine.

Comment: @manveti it does not handle arguments, so prob not a dupe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`functools.partial` can be used to create partial objects, which act like some other function with some arguments already passed. These can be given dynamically-generated names in the local namespace via the `locals()` dictionary or in the module namespace via the `globals()` dictionary (with the standard caveats about dictionaries and other structures being favorable to `globals()` in most use cases aside from the specific one in this question).

Putting those together would give you something like:

```
for shapename in ['a_circle', 'a_square', ...]:
  for is_patch_not_line in [False, True]:
    new_func_name = "draw_" + shapename + "_"
    if is_patch_not_line:
      new_func_name += "patch"
    else:
      new_func_name += "outline"
    globals()[new_func_name] = functools.partial(
      draw_a_shape,
      shapename=shapename,
      is_patch_not_line=is_patch_not_line,
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

The below seems to work. I had to create `make_new_draw_a_shape` to wrap the inner function because creating the inner function directly in the `for` loop was resulting in the last function generated assigned to all names.

```py
def draw_a_shape(ax, is_patch_not_line, shapename, **kwargs):
    print(f"is_patch_not_line={is_patch_not_line}, shapename={shapename}")


def make_new_draw_a_shape(is_patch_not_line, shapename):
    def new_draw_a_shape(ax, **kwargs):
        draw_a_shape(ax, is_patch_not_line, shapename, **kwargs)
    return new_draw_a_shape


for shapename in ['a_circle', 'a_square', 'an_ellipse']:
    for is_patch_not_line in [False, True]:
        new_func_name = "draw_" + shapename + "_"
        if is_patch_not_line:
            new_func_name += "patch"
        else:
            new_func_name += "outline"
        globals()[new_func_name] = make_new_draw_a_shape(is_patch_not_line, shapename)


draw_a_circle_patch(None)
draw_a_circle_outline(None)
draw_a_square_patch(None)
draw_a_square_outline(None)
draw_an_ellipse_patch(None)
draw_an_ellipse_outline(None)
```

Output:

```
is_patch_not_line=True, shapename=a_circle
is_patch_not_line=False, shapename=a_circle
is_patch_not_line=True, shapename=a_square
is_patch_not_line=False, shapename=a_square
is_patch_not_line=True, shapename=an_ellipse
is_patch_not_line=False, shapename=an_ellipse
```